# Amazon affiliate api

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

Does anybody has some experience with Product Advertising API of Amazon? 
I have a django site and I need to get the affiliate info that is relevant to my site.
Which python/django packages do you use and how?

Answer (score 2):

I am starting a similar project.  I haven't completed it yet, so I can't answer this perfectly yet, but here is an open source python project I've found related to the Amazon Product API on PyPi:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-amazon-product-api/